# Django object unique id value in Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

in this modal I have a foreign Key Named **stockCode** That key has duplicated values and I want to get only one of them(unique).

```
class Product(models.Model):
   stockCode = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=50,null=False, blank=False)
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=False, blank=False)
   Desc = models.CharField(max_length=120,null=True, blank=True)
   price1 = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
   price2 = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
   publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.stockCode)

class Stock(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    productId = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    sizeId = models.ForeignKey(Varyasyon,null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    colorId = models.ForeignKey(Renk,null=False, blank=False,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    grubId = models.ForeignKey(Grub,null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    stock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.grubId)
```

I've tried this:

```
@xframe_options_sameorigin
def product(request):
    stock = Stock.objects.all().values('productId').distinct()
    return render(request,"product.html",{"products":stock})
```

but it gives me only the id value
ant tried to add `.values('productId','productId__Name')` it gives me **productId__Name** unique value and I don't want this. I want only **productId** to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Postgres database, you can pass column names to the `distinct` function to tell Postgres which columns to check for distinctness. Otherwise the database will use the entire row to check for distinctness. See the documentation for `distinct` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

In your case:

```
stock = Stock.objects.all().values('productId__stockCode').distinct('productId__stockCode')
```

PS. I'd recommend to follow the [Django naming conventions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) because it will make your code easier to understand and use:

1. `productId` should rather be `product` because the `ForeignKey` references a `Product`. Django will create a `product_id` column in a migration.
2. `Name` should be lowercase `name`.
3. `stockCode` should be `stock_code`.